# How can I call image from outer folder of my react-app folder in react.js

Tags: reactjs, file, file-upload, image-upload, react-image

My image is stored in the **server** folder and my react app folder is **food**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m5eF.png)

I wanted to call images from **server(server>uploads>foods)** folder to **food(food>src>home)**. I was used back path like as **(../)** but it doesn't work.

So, how I can call images from the server folder to the food folder in react

How can I call image from outer folder of my react-app folder in react.js

Comment: I think it's not possible in this way. You can create a monorepo and use different files from different projects in the app.

Comment: What is server folder is ? Is it a another react project or something else ?

Comment: @Akshayphalphale I create 3 folders such as server, food, and dashboard. In the server folder just run the node.js and in another 2 folders run react-app.  My Node functionality will work from the server folder. So, I want to call images from the server folder to the food (react) folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you have to fetch image from server folder, which is your **express.js** application.

The images, CSS files, JavaScript files, and other files that the client downloads from the server are known as **static files**. These static files can be fetched with the use of the **express framework** and without the use of it.

you may have following directory tree:

```
server.js
package.json
package-lock.json
nodemodules
  | -- *
uploads
   -food
     | -- demoImage.png
public
  | -- index.html
```

Using the Express framework: Using the express framework its built-in middleware function **express.static()** can be used to serve static files.

**Filename:** server.js

```
// Requiring module
const express = require('express');
 
// Creating express object
const app = express();
 
// Defining port number
const PORT = 3000;                 
 
// Function to serve all static files
// inside public directory.
app.use(express.static('public')); 
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));
 
// Server setup
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Running server on PORT ${PORT}...`);
})
```

**Steps to run the program:**

1. Install express:

```
npm install express
```

2. Run the server.js file using the following command:

```
node server.js
```

**Now you can access image from following url:**

```
http://localhost:3000/images/demoImage.png
```